# Click in firebug console cancel jquery event on page

Tags: jquery, firebug

I have difficulities to explain clearly my problem in the title. Here is more explanations :

I'm trying to inspect a jedtable element (a plugin that allows a div to self transform to an input field in order to change div's value). So :

1. I click on the jeditable div
2. My jeditable input appear
3. I click on the element inspector in firebug
4. at that moment the jeditable input close so it's removed from the DOM so I can't inspect it ...

Is there a way to tell the page not to handle click in firebug panel ??

Any other solution to inspect my element would be great !

PS 1 : I have the FireQuery extension of FireBug installed (it works great to see attributes modified on the fly)
PS 2 : I'm under Firefox 24 on Ubuntu

Comment: use Google chrome Inspect element.

Comment: Very nice thanks. How do I mark the question is resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Google chrome Inspect element.

Read

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/part1/

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

Step1: open your web page and FireBug
 
Step2: Focus on your html tab(It will height-light the html element and its attribtes which one is updating currently )
Step3: Inspect your div and see what happen in html section when you trigger click on div.

I hope you will understand my point.

Comment: I tried but as the div content (in firebug) doesn't self open to show its content, when I return to firebug to click the + to display div's content, I loose ... its content ! If you have an option in order that firebug automaticaly open inspected element : I take. Anyway, thank you for helping.